# Can't access localhost/laravel in LAMP

Tags: laravel, lamp

I'm new to Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed LAMP and I install laravel in `/var/www` but it seems that I can't access `localhost/laravel` in my server it says.

[image]

So what I'm missing here?

**Edit:**
It works when i try `php artisan serve` then it gives me `localhost:8000` but when `localhost/laravel` it doesn't work.

Comment: What the errors say? Can you specific more detail?

Comment: It's means you haven't start your Apache. Have you already started?

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar Yes I did started it. localhost/phpmyadmin is working

Comment: Try out a php file and test it. It's was work or not. If that still haven't work check your Apache errors log.

Comment: Still doesn't work when I create a file in the directory

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your Apache is not working. You can start your Apache by the following command

`sudo service apache2 start`

You can see more about start/stop/restart Apache at [here](http://mixeduperic.com/ubuntu/how-to-start-stop-and-restart-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu.html).

Or if you want to re install your lamp, so you can see at [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)